# jquery bxslider carousel issue when resize

Tags: jquery, plugins, bxslider

i have a problem with bxslider carousel. im trying to make responsive web and im using resize method in js. im trying to make slider has 2 slides and then 1 slide by shrinking window width. 
But,,,, when i shrink window width, bxslider is not changing.....
below is my code. i searched a lot about this problem,, ppl ask to put reloadSlider or destroySlider but i dnt know where exactly put in this code,,

```
var slider;
    function bxslider(){
        if(width>555&&width<=765){
        slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2,
            slideWidth:400,
            moveSlides:1
        });
        slider.reloadSlider();
    }
    if(width<=555){
        var slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            slideWidth:0,
            moveSlides:1
       });
       slider.reloadSlider();
    }
}
$window.on('resize',function(){
    bxslider();
});
```

Comment: where did you define `width` in your `bxslider()` function?

Comment: i have another function above. so i defined width already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use This Code**

```
var slider;    
function bxslider(){
            var width = $(document).width();
        //alert(width);
        
        if(width>555&&width<=765){
        slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2,
            slideWidth:400,
            moveSlides:1
        });
        
    }
    if(width<=555){
        var slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            slideWidth:0,
            moveSlides:1
       });
       
    }
    slider.reloadSlider();
}
$(window).on("orientationchange load resize", function () {
    bxslider();
});
```

**[JsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/22euny7s/)**

**Edit:** try tu put your function slider.reloadSlider(); out side the if Condition .. I updated the answer check once again.

Comment: it works!! but the only strange thing is after reload the slide pager-item is not able to click,,, what's the matter with this?

Comment: @JoJay - I am not getting you .Please if possible for you post your code in jsfiddle and give me link then I can help you

Comment: @JoJay - did you removed the `alert()` statement from above code ?

Comment: here is my jsfiddle looks something wrong,, today is my first time to use jsfiddle   [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yejinjo/vz3m3jcd/)

Comment: the problem is even if i click bxslider pager there is no click event happened after resizing

Comment: @JoJay - I updated the answer - try with this and put your function slider.reloadSlider(); outside the `IF` statement

Comment: @Prog-its not working if i put reloadSlider outside if, in console i got undefined reloadSlider error,,,, hmmm whats the problem ㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: @Prog- thanks!! but i think it's not a coding or programing problem,, because im using resize method so guess 1px gap of window width can make error ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var slider;
    function bxslider(){
        if($(window).width()>555&&($(window).width()<=765){
        slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2,
            slideWidth:400,
            moveSlides:1
        });
        slider.reloadSlider();
    }
    if(($(window).width()<=555){
        slider=$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            slideWidth:0,
            moveSlides:1
       });

    }
}
$window.on('resize',function(){
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

Comment: i already tried,,, console make error like': Cannot read property 'reloadSlider' of undefined '

Comment: var slider was redefined for lower screen size. Made edit for this. Check now